# JSON in javascript block, insecure or merely an anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, php, json, xss

I was reading the [OWASP XSS prevention cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233.1_-_HTML_escape_JSON_values_in_an_HTML_context_and_read_the_data_with_JSON.parse) and noted that it considered the following piece of code an anti-pattern.

```
<script>
    var initData = <%= data.to_json %>; // Do NOT do this without encoding the data with one of the techniques listed below.
</script>
```

The alternative it suggested was this:

```
<script id="init_data" type="application/json">
    <%= html_escape(data.to_json) %>
</script>
```

...then in your javascript file:

```
var dataElement = document.getElementById('init_data');
var jsonText = dataElement.textContent || dataElement.innerText  // unescapes the content of the span
var initData = JSON.parse(jsonText);
```

However, the cheat sheet doesn't go into what is wrong with the original code.  Is it merely an anti-pattern, or is there an actual opportunity for XSS there?  It seems like PHP's `json_encode()` ought to correctly do all of the necessary escaping in order to turn it into a valid JSON object, and JSON is a close-enough subset of Javascript where it ought to just work as long as you escape U+2028 and U+2029.

Comment: If you properly encode it, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
<script>
var data = {"name":"</script><script>alert(1)//"}
</script>
```

This is valid json, but because the document is first parsed as HTML, the json will break and execute alert(1).